# Automate JFrame Bounds with respect to components size

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I have created a simple `JFrame` with two labels, two fields and two buttons. `ContentPane` with `BoxLayout` has a JPanel. JPanel with `MigLayout` have all the 6 components. Components are placed relatively and growable, but I am forced to give bounds to `JFrame`, which I would like to avoid. If I avoid `setBounds()`. Frame appears very small and it shows only `window buttons`. If I mention some size to `JFrame`, it can accomodate components well in `Windows` not in `Mac`(`Buttons` at bottom are truncated a little). Specifying greater frame size spares `look and feel` in `Windows`.

Is it possible to make a JFrame growing automatically with respect to its child components? or to make it accomodate everything dynamically without setting bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> make it accomodate everything dynamically without setting bounds?

Call [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. ..